Blurry images with telephoto lens at low f-number
I have a Nikon D7200 with a Tamron AF 70-300 mm 1:4-5.6 Tele-Macro lens. When I use low f-numbers, i.e. 5.6 (lowest possible at high focal lenghts), the image becomes very blurry. See example images below. The images becomes better at higher f-numbers. At very high f-numbers (45) there is a slight increase in blurriness again. All images below were taken at focal length of 280 mm and all images were taken with a tripod. The sheet music paper was about 8 m from the camera.
What is the reason for the blurriness at low f-numbers? Is it due to a low quality (or damaged) lens where there is significant abberations at large aperatures (low f-numbers). Is this the quality to be expected from a Tamron lens (or is it likely damaged) and should I expect more from a more expensive telephoto lens?
(I am guessing that the bluriness at very high f-numbers is due to diffraction limit effects with the very small aperature so this seems expected).
f = 5.6, 1/800:

f = 10, 1/250

f=16, 1/100:

f = 45, 1/60:


How are you focusing the images?

Camera autofocus. I also tried manual focusing but wasn't able to improve the images.

Is quality behaviour same when shooting objects far away?

It's very strange that you have better image at F16 than at F10 because diffraction already kicks in at F8.

How does lens portray with fine details like small LEDs or shiny glitter?

It could be that your lens doesn't focus well with the camera body, although, manual focus would have fixed that. 
Try using live view and see if things get better.
You don't mention the distance between subject and camera. Lenses have a minimum focus distance. If you are too close, focus will never be achieved. Camera bodies usually prevent you from taking the picture if the camera focus lock hasn't been achieved (this feature can be disabled).

It is very common for lenses to be less sharp at minimum f/#  because that includes the light/images from the periphery of the objective element... That light has to be bent more and travel a longer distance which makes it harder to focus correctly/equally. I.e. optical aberrations are greatest at the periphery.
However, that seems quite extreme IMO and I would guess there is something wrong with the lens; or perhaps a cheap filter is installed. I've never seen a lens that soft in the center of the field... but there is also a very large number of lenses I've never seen/used.
And yes, diffraction is limiting resolution/sharpness at higher f/#'s

Like StevenKerstig and DiggingDeep, I think part of the problem is that the lens is soft when very open.
However, this would give you very decent results at f/8, and since your f/10 test is still far from what you get at f/16, there is likely also a bit of a focusing problem and the f/16 shot is better because of the increased depth of field.
You said you tried manual focus, was it in the view finder or using a zoomed view in the rear screen?

Looking for the actual model of my lens I came across this review:
imaging-resource.com review of the Tamron 70-300mm f/4-5.6 Di LD Macro 1:2 AF
The review states:

As is often the case with inexpensive lenses, this entry-level Tamron is somewhat soft when used wide open. It becomes very soft as you approach the 300mm end of its zoom range. Closing the aperture by one stop improves matters greatly though, delivering respectable sharpness from 70 to about 180mm, while results at 300mm remain fairly soft. Closing down by two f-stops produces slight additional improvements, but results at 300mm never approach what we'd call sharp.

Which is exactly what I experience. So I guess a cheap lens requires large f-numbers/small apertures at the ends of the zoom range.

Your f/16 photo might be called "somewhat soft". The others are not "somewhat soft", they are unusable. There is almost certainly something wrong with your lens.
